# Type Error: Uploader must be instance of "Fileuploader" in angular migration 1.8version im using angular-ui-grid,inside in one cell using fileuploader

Tags: angularjs

**I try to use ng-if in div and scope.uploder=new fileuploader these two i tried. but the issue will be remains same its not working. please help I'm facing issue from 2 weeks onwards.**
please find below is the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bFau.png)

Comment: Try using `ng-show`

Comment: im using like this code in my project. <div class=row  nvfileselect="" uploader= uploader/>

Comment: nothing will change for using ng-show the error will be remains same .